# When should I say "a clear voice" over "clear voice"?

Tags: word-usage

I have a question about the usage of the word, voice.
When should I say "a clear voice" over "clear voice"?

I would like to say that

> A clear voice is one of the qualities for the job.

Is it right expression?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be a better fit for [ell.se].

Answer (score 2):

In answer to your question: Yes, "a clear voice" is a correct expression. "Clear voice" without the article "a" wouldn't work.

Now as a side note, your sentence might be improved by substituting the word "requirements" for "qualities," like so:

> A clear voice is one of the requirements for the job.

Comment: Just for reference, I found the following sentence [here][1]:

The most important characteristic of a radio announcer is a well-modulated and pleasant voice, and the ability to speak persuasively and intelligently.

  [1]: http://work.chron.com/radio-announcer-educational-requirements-13903.html